# How to set breakpoints in visualforce Gauge?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageController">
  <html>

<apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" legend="true" data="{!data}" >
    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="left" margin="-10" 
       minimum="0" maximum="10000" steps="2000" />
    <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="score" highlight="true" tips="true" donut="60" 
        colorSet="#FF0000,#FACC2E,#31B404,#8A084B">

    </apex:gaugeSeries>    
</apex:chart>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class TestPageController {   

    public TestPageController(){

    }

    public List<gaugeData> getData() {
        double NPS_score = 0;
        Account score = [Select Id, Name, Amount_1__c, Amount_2__c,AnnualRevenue  From Account Where id='001i000000cxxM4' LIMIT 1];
         Account score1 = [Select Id, Name,  Amount_1__c From Account LIMIT 1];
        List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_1__c));
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_2__c));
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.AnnualRevenue));



        return data;
    }
    public class gaugeData {
        public String name { get; set; }

        public decimal score { get; set; }



        public gaugeData(String name, decimal npsScore) {
            this.name = name;


            this.score = npsScore;

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output Image]

My question is how to set just 3/4 breakpoints [e.g : 5000,15000,25000,50000] instead of having so much breakpoints in gauge?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that with `<apex:gaugeSeries`. Though `<apex:axis` supports a steps attribute, but it is only applicable when `type="numeric"`.

About type attribute Salesforce says. "An integer value that specifies the number of tick marks to places on the axis. If set, it overrides the automatic calculation of tick marks for the axis. **Valid only when the axis type is Numeric.**"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_axis.htm